# Can't find Behave's configuration file

Tags: python, python-behave

I'm creating automated test scripts using the Python [behave](https://github.com/behave/behave) framework. I wanted to edit my `behave` configuration file (`behave.ini`), but I can't find it.

Where is the file located? Do I need to create the file myself in the home directory?

Answer (score 1):

Behave has an excellent and complete documentation, I recommend you always check there first. Now, to answer your question, here's the documentation for the [configuration files](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/behave.html#configuration-files)

Answer (score 1):

***Please follow the steps to add a customize configuration file for default properties***

1. **Create behave.ini file and features file at the same level**

[image]

2. set properties in this file, which you want to run default, for example i have set default_tags=@defaulttag

[image]

3. Now when i run the `behave` command, then it execute only scenario that has a tag @defaulttag

[image]

Comment: Intellij has a plugin to identify .ini file, don't choose a type as text when you create it